# Converting SDL2 color keyed Surface to Texture, no transparent pixels

Tags: c, image, sdl-2

I'm dabbling with SDL2 programming while following the excellent tutorials at Lazy Foo. I'm still far behind with it but I've found an odd inconsistency between what the tutorials shows and what I've been able to obtain while following them: when creating an `SDL_Texture` from an `SDL_Surface` through the `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` function I always lose the transparent background obtained with the `SDL_SetColorKey` function.

This is the function I wrote to load a texture from a file:

```
SDL_Texture *LoadTexture(char *path, SDL_Renderer *renderer) {
    SDL_Texture *newTexture = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *loadedSurface = NULL;
    loadedSurface = loadSurfaceWithKey(path);

    newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface);
    if (newTexture == NULL) {
    printf("Error while creating texture. SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);

    return newTexture;
}
```

While `loadSurfaceWithKey` is your usual function loading an image and storing it in an `SDL_Surface` after setting the background color as the color key.

I made a simple program that asks the user wether to use Surfaces or Textures, and show a single image for 5 seconds. These are the results:
[image]

I'm 100% sure I'm keying the right color since I have no problems with it while using Surfaces. To make this problem even stranger I tried compiling [Lazy Foo's Color Keying tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/10_color_keying/index.php) code and the stick man sprite is correctly drawn to the screen with a transparent background, while switching the sprite with one made by me (while using the same color for the background of course) still doesn't work:

[image]

I observed this behaviour both under OSX and Windows 7, and both by using png images and bmp.

I know I could bypass this problem entirely by making the images background transparent by myself, and I guess there are many other methods to make the background transparent while using `SDL_Textures`, but I can't for the life of me understand why this method works with Lazy Foo's sprite but it doesn't work with the ones I made.

Comment: What is your image format? Make sure it is *not* RGBA, since alpha doesn't play well with key colour.

Comment: The problem was the Alpha channel indeed. Removing it from the PNGs worked like a charm, I still haven't tested with BMPs but I guess it will work with those too. This poses the question why working with only Surfaces never posed a problem though, anybody knows something more about this?

Comment: Blitting [rules](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface) aren't too simple. When you blit to screen, it is RGBA->RGB (since screen have no alpha), but when you blit to target texture instead (haven't checked actual code - just a logical guess) - it is RGBA->RGBA (target texture is RGBA) and follows different logic. I don't think BMP can have alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with R,G,B as your color key you need.

```
loadedSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(path); 
// or 
// loadedSurface = IMG_Load(path); // You must #include "SDL_image.h"
SDL_SetColorKey(loadedSurface ,SDL_TRUE,SDL_MapRGB(loadedSurface ->format,R,G,B));
newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface);
SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);
```